# WCF SOAP Message body changing output tag for single vs list response

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

We are having an issue where the WCF XML Serializer is changing the tag of an output object if the response is a single object, but if it's a list of the object, then it's correct.

This is the response for the list item

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    ...
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <ListObjectsResponse xmlns="http://our.namespace/">
            <ListObjectsResult>
                <Object>
                ...
                </Object>
                <Object>
                ...
                </Object>
                ...
            </ListObjectsResult>
        </ListObjectsResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

You can see we have a bunch of  `<Object>` elements under the `<ListObjects>` result.

If we then call another method that only returns a single `<Object>` this is the result:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    ...
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <GetObjectResponse xmlns="http://our.namespace/">
            <GetObjectResult>
                ...
            </GetObjectResult>
        </GetObjectResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

You can see that the `<Object>` tag no longer exists and is has been changed to a `<GetObjectResult>`.

We would have expected to see an xml response for a single item like:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    ...
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <GetObjectResponse xmlns="http://our.namespace/">
            <GetObjectResult>
                <Object>
                    ...
                </Object>
            </GetObjectResult>
        </GetObjectResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Is the XML response being generated incorrect, or are we being silly and we shouldn't be worring about the XML itself?